# creating Initramfs in Yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, u-boot, initramfs

I wanted to create initramfs in yocto. Therefore I created a custom recipe, added following lines;
require recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "${INITRAMFS_FSTYPES}"

It built successfully. I am not sure if all works properly. 
I guess kernel and u-boot also need to be configured.

My question is, does yocto configure kernel and u-boot automatically after seeing
 IMAGE_FSTYPES = "${INITRAMFS_FSTYPES}" or I should configure them myself?

Thank you.
Best regards

Answer (score 3):

creating a new image-initramfs.bb image, and adding

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

include original-image.bb

IMAGE_FSTYPES = "${INITRAMFS_FSTYPES}"
PACKAGE_INSTALL = "${IMAGE_INSTALL}"
```

And then in conf/local.conf

```
INITRAMFS_IMAGE = "image-initramfs"
INITRAMFS_IMAGE_BUNDLE = "1"
```

Where `image-initramfs` is the initramfs image recipe name.